# Codeigniter Warning: failed to open stream in mpdf: No such file or directory

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

I'm using mpdf in my codeigniter web app for converting one of my view as pdf and to attach it while sending email. I've downloaded and moved mpdf library to the library folder. But when i try to email the pdf, i'm getting the following warning:

`A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: require_once(/application/libraries/mpdf/includes/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Filename: mpdf/mpdf.php
Line Number: 55`

But actually `functions.php` file is present in the `mpdf/includes/' folder. Can anyone find where am going wrong?

Comment: your code is already in `application` directory so there is no way that path will be valid

Answer (score 0):

Use the APPPATH constant like this

require_once(APPATH."libraries/mpdf/includes/functions.php");

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/mpdf/includes/functions.php');
```

or

```
require_once(FCPATH.'application/libraries/mpdf/includes/functions.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because Linux is case-sensitive in file names. Review that aspect in detail.